# JIRA OAuth via cURL

Tags: php, rest, post, get, jira

I need to authenticate my application in Jira using OAuth and cURL. 
When I send a GET request to /plugins/servlet/oauth/request-token I get HTTP 200 header without any body or token (with or without parameters - same result).

But if I try to use a POST request or pass data throught header I always get HTTP 400 and the following string: 
**"oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_consumer_key&oauth_problem=parameter_absent"**

Here is some code:

```
$ar = array(
    "oauth_consumer_key" => $CONSUMER_KEY,
    "oauth_nonce" => "1245003598",
    "oauth_signature" => $sign,
    "oauth_signature_method" => "RSA-SHA1",
    "oauth_timestamp" => time()
);


$req = $server . "/plugins/servlet/oauth/request-token";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $ar);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

The server running on PHP 5.3.2.

Any thoughts?

Thank you and best regards,
TheDiamondDoge

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Curl but are working on this same issue (not much to find about it).

The oauth parameters must be added to the URL or to the body in the call to request-token (not as an Authorization header). Have a look at the python sample included with this repo: https://bitbucket.org/atlassian_tutorial/atlassian-oauth-examples?_ga=2.159768701.1920570172.1527580410-815193204.1519142635.

Unfortunately the Java example included in the samples is wrong. It works when calling Jira Online, but fails on other instances (might be version related).